# Live "new question grey bar " seldom happens

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Usually I stalk the JavaScript tags of StackOverflow and I just recently changed residence. From where I was from, StackOverflow usually pops in new questions live with that gray bar saying "N new questions". Clicking it loads the new questions on the same page.

Now, that I'm in my new residence, when I stalk that section, I notice that no "gray bar" happens. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. I often times click the "newest" tab only to find out it loads 20+ questions. The gray bar never appeared.

Is there some issue regarding this?

Comment: Never saw that gray bar at stackoverflow, only here on meta.

Comment: Perhaps you're behind a proxy that kills the websockets now?

Comment: @Zuul Stack Overflow has the grey bar on the /questions/tagged pages, but not on the main page.

Comment: No repro - just checked Java, and sure enough - a notification of new activity.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, on the tag pages. It shows up sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: So, @Joseph, the server times on [that test page](http://websocketstest.com/) keep updating, even when keeping the page open for a long time, right? If you know where to find it, the Network tab in Web Inspector or Firebug might reveal if the connection is started okay (which should show `101 Switching Protocols` for `ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/`). I don't think transmission can easily be faulty, given it's TCP/IP. (But then: Stack Exchange [is using its home grown implementation](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2012/04/12/what-weve-been-up-to/); not sure at what network level that starts.)

Comment: @Arjan I tested 2 times and checked Dev Tools, 4 and 6 socket connections respectively. They all show success, but the console writes `Unexpected response code: 503` for each request.

Answer (score 1):

Web sockets are enabled for Stack Overflow on tag pages only.  I have confirmed they are working, you might want to check if your network is allowing web socket traffic.

Comment: Yes, I meant the tag pages. I use the same browser and OS in both places. The only difference would be the ISP. Could the ISP be blocking it?

Comment: No idea - you can try:  http://websocketstest.com/ to get a pretty good idea if web sockets are working.

Comment: Any chance you're on wireless, @Josepp, *and* might be switching from one access point to the other? Be sure to see the server time change  as long as you have http://http://websocketstest.com open.

Comment: @Arjan nope, im wired. And all green on the socket tests by Geoff. Could it be just failed transmissions?